# Can't set a date time in one of my entity framework objects, says NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, nullreferenceexception

I have a ChatSequence entity with a DateTimeCreated property that's a DateTime.
But when I try and set it, I get an exception that's saying nullreferenceexception

I'm setting it like this

```
ChatSequence newSequence = new ChatSequence();
sequence.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

and here is the object

```
public class ChatSequence
{
    [Key]
    public int ChatSequenceId { get; set; }

    public int TotalMessages { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int ToYogaProfileRefId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ToYogaProfileRefId")]
    public virtual YogaProfile ToProfile { get; set; }

    //[Index]
    //public int FromId { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public int FromYogaProfileRefId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FromYogaProfileRefId")]
    public virtual YogaProfile FromProfile { get; set; }


    [Index]
    public DateTime LastMessageSent { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int PartitionId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but your first code snippet creates `newSequence` yet tries to set a value on `sequence`.

Comment: maybe it's late, but ya, I want to create a new object 'newSequence' and fill it with values before I save it to my db

Comment: Is your object **sequence** instantiated? In your code, only **newSequence** is instantiated.

Comment: ahhhh yes, it's a typeo! it's late. 3AM

Comment: sequence is coming from another section above!!

Comment: should I delete this question or just leave it...?

Comment: I *would* delete it but I don't think you can if there's an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in your code. You have created an object with the different name and setting value on different..

```
ChatSequence newSequence = new ChatSequence();
sequence.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Try this ..

```
ChatSequence newSequence = new ChatSequence();
newSequence.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
```